# How to add PHP in netbeans on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, netbeans

I just downloaded Netbeans for Ubuntu. Now I only have Java, how can I add PHP to it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to **Tools**->**Plugins**

On the **Installed** tab check **`PHP`** and click on **Activate**. Restart NetBeans.

Note: *I assume you have downloaded the appropriate package containing PHP tools.*

---

On 7.0.1 go to **Tools**->**Plugins**

click the **Settings** tab and **Activate** the Update Centers.

Now click the **Available Plugins** tab and you should see **PHP**

Install and Reboot Netbeans.

---

On 8.1, same as above for 7.0.1 but some more precision : on the **Settings** tab you need to tick the **NetBeans Distribution** checkbox to see PHP in the Available Plugins list.

Answer (score 4):

Activate the Update Centers. = click update tab > click Update button. now the Available Plugins will refresh then click on Available Plugins tab scroll down you will see php check it and click Install button

Comment: +1 If on "Available plugins" is empty than you should to check all inside "Update Centers" then click on "Active plugins" tab to see updated available plugins.